# Execute ssh command with system()

Tags: c++, linux, ssh

I have a C++ application (under linux) which open a ssh reverse tunnel. This works well. But i have some trouble to close the connection. 
The close command will work like it should when i start the application from the command line, but when i start the application from a cron job in background, the connection will not be closed.

Here my code:

Open connection:

```
std::string cmd = "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -f -N -T -M -R 8003:192.168.0.1:8001 -R 8007:192.168.0.1:8005 -R 22222:localhost:22 sshService";
system(cmd.c_str());
```

To close the connection i use:

```
std::string cmd = "ssh -T -O exit sshService";
system(cmd.c_str());
```

My host configuration is:

```
Host sshService
    HostName www.addressOfServer.com
    User sshUser
    ControlPersist 4h
    ControlPath ~/.ssh/sshService.ctl
    IdentityFile /home/user/sshUser
```

Are there some ideas, what i make wrong? Or some ideas how i can find out the problem?

Comment: Not enough privilege for the closing command? try setting root's setuid to your closing command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. It looks that i have to use a  tmpfs path for the  Control Path....
I changed the configuration to:

```
Host sshService
    HostName www.addressOfServer.com
    User sshUser
    ControlPersist 4h
    ControlPath /tmp/sshService.ctl
    IdentityFile /home/user/sshUser
```